# How can I store multiple data using asyncstorage in React Native?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have used the asyncstorage for storing the data but I think it's storing only one entry at a time that's because when I tried to print the value it only showed the last signup details and the too only on console instead of screen.
**What I want:**

1. Store data of all the users.
2. Print all the details on the screen.

Due to formatting issue I was not able to attach the code. Please check my code on this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XgvN-z4ALG8AlXzonAmUzuzik8KgEVGr?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Async storage isnt really meant for state management. Its for having data that will persist between app opens and closes. Some examples of this is using it to save a user auth token, or to keep track of the user defined settings.

Here's a quick [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/3JNPL1Zks)

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput, Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const someDataKey = '@someData';

export default function App() {
  const [someData, setSomeData] = useState({
    token: null,
    userId: null,
    expiresAt: '',
  });
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const submit = () => {
    // fake server call to get token
    setSomeData({
      token:getRandomChars(50),
      userId:Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+1,
      expiresAt:Date.now()+60*60*24*4
    })
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const dataAsString = await AsyncStorage.getItem(someDataKey);
      if (dataAsString) setSomeData(JSON.parse(someData));
    };
    getData();
  }, []);
  useEffect(()=>{
      AsyncStorage.setItem(someDataKey,JSON.stringify(someData))
  },[someData])
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {!someData.token ? (
        <>
          <TextInput
            value={email}
            label="Enter email"
            onChangeText={setEmail}
            style={styles.input}
            dense
          />
          <TextInput
            value={password}
            label="Password"
            onChangeText={setPassword}
            style={styles.input}
            dense
          />
          <Button onPress={submit}>Login</Button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
        <Text>Last session retrieved</Text>
        <Text>Token:{someData.token}</Text>
        <Text>User ID:{someData.userId}</Text>
        <Button onPress={()=>{
          setSomeData({})
        }}>Reset data</Button>
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  input: {
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
});

const getRandomChars = (len=20)=>{
  const chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
  let str =''
  while(str.length <len){
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random()*chars.length)
    str+=chars[index]
  }
  return str
}
```

Before the data was saved to storage, reloading the page would show the login form; but once the data is set, the data is retrieved, omitting the login part